# NullPointerException in class Company

Tags: java

There is two classes: worker and company.
In company class there are:

```
public class Company {
    private worker[] p;
    private int currentID;
    private String nameCO;

    Company(String cNameCO){this.nameCO = cNameCO;}

    public boolean hireWorker(worker w){
        p[this.currentID].setName(w.getName));
        p[this.currentID].setSurName(w.getSurName));
        return true;
}
```

In the end theres an error `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

What's wrong? Please, help.

Comment: you haven't initialized your worker-array and your currentID - so on trying to access a field of the array with initial value for an int (= 0) there is actually non - but you try to access the setName-method there

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I think you need to change:
1. `private worker[] p;` is not initialized.
2. `w.getName` and `w.getSurName` are methods and should end with a pair of parentheses `()`

Also, please use a growing and shrinking data structure like an `ArrayList<>` since there aren't going to be a fixed number of employees.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `p` is `null` because you haven't set it to anything.

```
 private Worker[] p = new Worker[100];
```

However a better choice is to use a list like this.

```
 private final List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();

 public void hireWorker(Worker w) {
     workers.add(w);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `p`, `p[ this.currentID ]` or `worker w` is null, debugging will definitely help. Plus `getName` and `getSurName` doesn't look like correct method invocation, you sure the provided code compiles?

My pick would be you didn't initialise `p` with a value, resulting in `null` for it as default (for objects).

Comment: the [default value for a not-defined integer is 0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) so the NPE is actually thrown on accessing p[0].setName(...) as there is no worker-object there. (By the way, I figured just out on linking the datatypes that with Java 8 int will be able to hold unsigned values with the help of Integer.class :))

Comment: Thanks for describing my point man, that's what I meant when I said that `p[ this.currentID ]` is null - regardless the index as if the problem was there an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException was issued before an NPE - as this is not the case I presume index to be valid either default one or custom one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorry but my english is very bad. I'm going to try explain you what is wrong in this code.

In the public boolean function hireWorker you need close whit '}'.

After that you modify the vector p[] but in any site you initialize this array. Then when you do p[1].setName('herius') java throw java.lang.NullPointerException.

You need initializace the vector fist.